# Category Conditional

Tags: categories, conditionals

This works fine but I want to “limit” the number of times the snippet shows up at the top of each entry, I only want it to show up on the top (one time in category “7”, no mater haw many entries.

Any suggestions?

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="event_calendar" style="linear" }
<h2><a href="{path='events/show/'}" />{category_name}</a></h2>
{/exp:channel:categories} 

{exp:channel:entries channel="event_calendar" dynamic="no"}

{if category_id == "7"} {snippet-rodeo-intro}{/if}

<h2 class="event-header">{event_name}</h2> 
{event_description}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative answer, doesn't use any additional plugins or anything.

I am assuming you want a category jump list a the top (hence the categories tag pair), then the entries in a decending fashion, grouped by category, with a snippet at the top of each category right?

Assuming this, what I've done is make a category loop, then use an inner entries loop to display the entries just for the outer category. Finally we use the `{absolute_count}` tag to target just the first entry.

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="event_calendar" style="linear" }
  <h2><a href="{path='events/show/'}" />{category_name}</a></h2>
{/exp:channel:categories} 

{exp:channel:categories channel="event_calendar" style="linear"}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="event_calendar" dynamic="no" category="{category_id}"}
    {if category_id == "7" && absolute_count == 1} 
      {snippet-rodeo-intro}
    {/if}

    <h2 class="event-header">{event_name}</h2> 
    {event_description}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I think you might get away with just adding `cat_limit="1"` to your channel:entries tag. More on this [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#id28).

If that doesn't do what you want, the other option is to simply post a flag to a variable when you display the snippet and a test for it being set.  There are various EE extensions that allow you to write to variables during execution - this uses [CE_Variables](https://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-variables/user-guide/variables), but there are many others.

```
{if category_id == "7" AND {exp:ce_vars:snippet_flag} != "1"}
 {snippet-rodeo-intro}
 {exp:ce_vars:set snippet_flag="1"}
{/if}
```

HTH